# How to hide or deactivate a TextField and a Label with javafx

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, fxml

I would like to hide or deactivate a `TextField` and its `Label` in my JavaFX application.

This is what I tried

```
myTextField.setVisible(false);
```

, but it's not working

I use Eclipse V4.5.0 on windows 7 with jfx8 V2.0.0

Comment: if you want your `TextField` to be also _collapsed_ while hidden, use: `myTextField.setManaged(false);`

Comment: I actually don't know how to hide it so...

Comment: What's your Java/JavaFX version and on which platform are you ?

Comment: I'm working with Eclipse and Jfx8

Comment: Could you edit your post with the exact version of Java, IDE and OS you are on ? Also, edit your post with what *exactly* happens instead of _it's not working_. A screenshot of the situation may also be useful.

Comment: Actually nothing happened when I launch it my Textfield still visible.

Comment: check this post..
it maybe of some help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069355/how-to-deactivate-a-textfield-and-a-label-by-combobox-selection-in-javafx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is difference between hiding and deactivating a TextField in JavaFX.

**To Hide :-** 
You need to set the visible property to false.

The possible reason's why its not working in your case is that if you have skipped mentioning the fx:id for your TextField or Label.

To do so just go through the fxml if using and set the fx:id="myTextField" , and then the same code that you have write will start to work.

The same is used to hide any Label.

**To Deactivate :-** There is a field named as disable just set that disable property to true to disable or deactivate any field.

Answer (score 6):

I understand that you want to hide/show a text field (javaFX), i usually use the same method you mentioned
assume that the text field variable name is field then:

to hide it use

```
field.setVisible(false);
```

to show it use

```
field.setVisible(true);
```

and it works always for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that I understand correctly your question, but I will try to answer to what I understand.

if you only want to deactivate `TextField` you can use:

```
myTextField.setEditable(false);
```

This will not "hide" the `TextField` it will be only not editable.

Based on your provided code, the problem might be in static created (in the FXML) `TextField`. What I suggest is to try and create the `Pane` and the `TextField` dynamically in the runtime.
Here is simple example how to create and use JavaFX components in the runtime :

```
public class ButtonInPane extends Application{ 
// Override the start method in the Application class
Button btn=new Button("OK");
HBox cont;
TextField myTextField;

public void start(Stage stage1){ 


    Label myLable=new Label("Some Lable");
    myTextField=new TextField("Some text");
    cont=new HBox();
    cont.getChildren().addAll(myLable,myTextField);

    Stage stage = new Stage(); //this instead of JFrame
    FlowPane pane2 = new FlowPane(); //this instead of JPanel

    pane2.getChildren().addAll(btn,cont);  
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 250, 50);
    stage.setTitle("Button in a FlowPane"); // Set the stage title
    stage.setScene(scene2); // Place the scene in the stage
    stage.show(); // Display the stage
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    //set event 
    setEventActions();
}
private void handlePlayAction() {
    cont.setVisible(false);

    //OR  myTextField.setVisible(false);

}
private void setEventActions() {
    this.btn.setOnAction(event -> this.handlePlayAction());
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{ launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: I've post something 4 days ago that were very clear and no answer so ... For your answer the first part is a good thing I should try it. And I don't understand the second part about Hbox ?   If you want to understand better what i want I invite you to read that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369702/hide-textfields-and-label-on-a-combobox-event-with-javafx

Comment: I believe the problem is that your `TextField` not created dynamically. Try creating it in the runtime.

Comment: How should I do that ? Never use dinamic Textfield it's my first javafx application.

Comment: Here is what I understand about this code tell me if I'm wrong : It open a new window with TextFields and label instead of hiding the others ? (It's a good idea I thought it was harder than create and hide the Label and TextField). Could you explain me what is the Hbox ?

Comment: Sure, `HBox` is like `JPanel` only it's aligning the objects horizontally

Comment: When does that new window is going to appear ? Because I don't understand when is it called.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What window?

Comment: The code you gave me open a new window with a Label and a TextField or I'm wrong ? Because I don't really understand it to be honnest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89061/discussion-between-seiran-and-david).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`myTextField.setDisable(true);`

It will disable field for a particular Action.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this for a Label in your `.fxml` file like this:

```
<Label layoutX="349.0" layoutY="85.0" 
   text="Label" visible="false" fx:id="actionSuccessLabel"/>
```

and then display it later in your Controller class like this:

```
actionSuccessLabel.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to do the **setVisible** or the visible property binding **after** the new function.

```
TextField textField = new TextField(field.getValue());
textField.visibleProperty().bind(field.getVisibleProperty());
```